# Assigning an array of structure to another array of same structure

Tags: .net, vb.net, boxing, unboxing

In Vb.net I am trying to assign an array of structure to another array of same structure

```
  Dim info() As assemblyInfo
  Dim info2() As assemblyInfo

    Structure assemblyInfo
        Dim Name As String
        Dim ClassTpys() As ClassTyp
    End Structure

Private Sub test()

info2 = info
```

any change in ifo gets reflected in info2, this assignmnet is happening byRef.

I don't want any change in info to get reflected in info2 and vice-versa, after the assignment, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `info2=info` is just assigning the reference of info to info2.  Try `info.CopyTo(info2, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Array is reference type so when you assign it you assign reference to it actually.
You need `Array.Copy` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx